# input for arraylist using readline() of BufferedReader

Tags: collections, readline

I am trying to take input and add them in an arraylist, using BufferedReader.
The code is taking endless inputs and it is not advancing to further lines (not exiting the for-loop).
Please find my below code:

```
public class ALinput {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            int n2 = br.read();// number of items in the list

            ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int i =1;i<=n2;++i)
            {
                list2.add(br.readLine());
            }

            System.out.println(list2);//printing list before sorting
            Collections.sort(list2);//sorting the list
            System.out.println("After sorting "+list2);

}
}
```

I have taken n2 as number of elements in the array list.
if input n2 = 5;
the readLine keeps on taking text input endlessly without exiting after 5 strings are added to the arraylist. 
Its not coming out of the for loop. Please help me understand the mistake I am doing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually isn't going forever, the character code for a zero is 48, one is 49, two is 50, and so on. so when you type in a 5, the computer reads it's character value, and stores n2 as 53, and let's you type in 52 inputs. why 52 instead of 53?
well theres a second mistake, `br.read()` only looks at the first byte of input, so one character. the first time `br.readLine()` is called, it finishes reading whatever was on the line after the first number you typed. to fix these problems, just change

```
int n2 = br.read();
```

to

```
int n2 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

and voila! done!
P.S. you might want to surround the `Integer.parseInt()` in a try catch block, in case the user types in something besides a number.